# How to fetch the array in the factory in laravel and to Array to string Conversion error?

Tags: php, laravel

I have factory like the below,

```
$factory->define(Customer::class, function (Faker $faker) {
 $result =  Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 1
)
       
           $count = count($result);
           
           for($i =0 ; $i<$count; $i++)
           {
              $id = $result[$i]. "\n";
              echo $id;

           }
      return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'customer_id' => $id, // I don't need to use faker here
        'Address' => $faker->address,
        
    ];
});
```

I want to pass the **result array to the customer_id inside the factory one by one**. Anyone could please help?

Here is my seeder

```
  private function addCompany()
    {
    
       factory(App\Company::class, 4)->create()->each(function ($data) {
        // Each company has 3 customers

            $customer= factory(App\Customer::class, 3)->make();//12 customers
            $data->customers()->saveMany($customer);
}
```

Model:
**customer model**

```
 public function customers() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Customer', 'company_id', 'id');
    }
```

How can I extract the **result array**? The customer_id which is in the array should not be repeated for the particular company.
Like the above, we have 3 customers for each company

```
Company_id      customer_id
1                 6
1                 5 
1                 4 
2                 4
2                 6
2                 1
3                 2
3                 5
3                 3
4                 2     // In this case,'2' should not be repeated for the single company_id (4)
4                 2
4                 3
```

**Each company_id should not contain repeated customer_id like the above.**

**How can I insert the array into the factory and seed the database with extracted array?**

**Got Array to String conversion error** .

Anyone could please help?
thanks

Comment: Dows this answer your question? [Laravel: How can i generate two unique seeds in my laravel faker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747382/laravel-how-can-i-generate-two-unique-seeds-in-my-laravel-faker)

Comment: @steven Thanks for your support. I need to fetch the array from the API, So I think I don't need to use faker here.

Comment: on which line is it throwing the `Array to string conversion` error. The most likely cause is when you try to use an `array` in the context of `string`. i.e if you try `echo $result`. This will throw the error. Kindly post **stack traces**  in your question.

Answer (score -1):

```
 'customer_id' => $faker->unique()->numberBetween(1,20),
```

[unique()](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#modifiers)
[numberBetween()](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#fakerproviderbase)

## Alternatively

```php
$customer_ids = array_values($result);

// ...
 return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'customer_id' =>  $faker->unique()->randomElement($customer_ids),
        'Address' => $faker->address,
        
    ];
/// ...
```